# How to block spam blocks pointing to a same website

Tags: spam

My blog continuously receive spam comments like below:

> I simply want to say I am new to blogs and truly liked this web-site.
>   More than likely I’m want to bookmark your blog post . You absolutely
>   have impressive well written articles. Thanks a lot for sharing your
>   web site.

They don't have a common user name, use all different email addresses and ip addresses and the content are hard to distinguish. But they all point to a same link: ziordeoipaazaraga.com

I searched through the current stop spam plugins but haven't figured out the one works for me. Is there a plugin which can help resolving this issue?

Comment: This is going to be closed because plugin recommendations are off-topic here. But if you want to do it with codes, you can hook into the comment processing action, check if the URL matches with that one, and then cancel it.

Comment: @ChristineCooper I can do it with code. However, I still want to keep it as the last option unless there is no easier way.

Comment: Absolutely. As far as I know, that would be the quickest approach than installing a plugin that does tons of other things that you don't need. ;-)

Comment: @ChristineCooper can you please let me know where should I insert the code. I am new to wp and php programming but it should be similar.

Comment: If you are new with WordPress developement, read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into enabling the Akismet add-in (free  at https://akismet.com/), which is pretty effective in blocking common comment spam.

There are many comment spam blockers available as plugins; including my own 'FormSpammerTrap'. All (including mine; found in the repository to reduce self-promotion) have various levels of success, you will need to try them to see which one works best for you.

There are also settings in Settings, Discussion that will allow you to approve all comments from new commenters.

**Added**

You could write your own code that would look for specific text, but that would not be efficient...all it would take is for the spammer to make a slight change to their text and your code wouldn't catch it.

Using Akismet will catch common spammers, but no solution will catch all of the spammers. What one hopes is that the spam-catchers will catch most of the comment spam, leaving only a few for you to remove manually.

You can also add captchas to your comment form, but those are not very user-friendly, and can be defeated. Hidden fields are easily sensed by the spam-bot, and questions ('what is 3+6?') is also not effective. Even my techinique (watching for focus/click on required fields) can be defeated by non-automated spammers.

What you are looking for is something that will catch most of the spam comments. But you will never find a complete/catch-everything solution. The best you can hope for is something that catches most of them.

Comment: why no links? :( if you are going to answer an off topic question. at least make it a good answer ;)

Comment: I added the Akismet link, plus more info. Didn't add the link to my plugin, since I didn't want to self-promote my solution over others. It's in the repository, so can be found. More info added that a full solution is not going to happen, but even a roll-you-own for specific text will not be efficient or long-lasting.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with self promotion as long as it is explicit and relevant